# Crossjoin in Cascading

Tags: java, cascading

I'd like to crossjoin two streams of tuples in Cascading. Let's suppose there are two lists: ladies and gentlemen, and the goal is to write all the possible lady-gentleman combinations out to a file (e.g. all the possible matches from the "women seeking men" section of a hypothetical dating website).

I found a similar example on [this blog](http://spryinc.com/blog/cascading-using-bufferjoin-perform-custom-joins) and attempted to tweak the code to make a crossjoin (see https://github.com/alexwoolford/cascading-crossjoin-stackoverflow-question).

The `operate` method in the `Crossjoin` class throws a null-pointer. Firstly, the `getJoinerClosure()` call in this line returns `null`:

```
JoinerClosure joinerClosure = bufferCall.getJoinerClosure();
```

... and then the `if` statement that immediately follows tries to get the size of `null`:

```
if( joinerClosure.size() != 2 )
    [...]
```

... resulting in a null-pointer exception.

Can you see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I removed the `rhsGroupFields` argument from the `new CoGroup` constructor, i.e. changed from:

```
Pipe pipeLadiesAndGentlemen = new CoGroup(pipeLadies, Fields.NONE, pipeGentlemen, Fields.NONE, new Fields("lady", "gentleman"), new BufferJoin());
```

.. to:

```
Pipe pipeLadiesAndGentlemen = new CoGroup(pipeLadies, Fields.NONE, pipeGentlemen, Fields.NONE, new BufferJoin());
```